# PHP Deprecated Error Message when Triming String

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I have a php code that contains lines that are deprecated can anyone help.

```
<?php
include('config.php');

session_start(); // Starting Session

$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($dbhost_name, $db_username, $db_password, $database , 3306);


// Check connection
if($con->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);
                             }

// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);


// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'";

$result = $con->query($sql);

$rows = $result->fetch_assoc(); 




if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}

$con->close(); // Closing Connection
}
}

?>
```

Below is the code.

Below is the error message.

[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to bind parameters to your queries and remove any `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** `mysql` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Replace `mysql_` functions with `mysqli_` functions

Change from

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

To

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
```

Answer (score -1):

The function `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated [1].

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead [2].

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

[2] http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't that what the question is about?